# When is it possible to have integer (or even rational) solution to Solving $n+1$, degree $n$ equations in $n$ variables

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations

Let $n$ be an integer and assume that I have $n+1$ many polynomial functions of degree $n$, in $n$ variables, namely
$$f_{1}(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}), f_{2}(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}), \ldots, f_{n+1}(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) $$ and I want to determine when the system of equations

$$f_{1}(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) = k_{1} \\ f_{2}(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) = k_{2}, ... \\ ... \\ ... \\ f_{n+1}(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) = k_{n+1}$$ has solutions for some $k_{1}, \ldots, k_{n+1} \in\mathbb{Z}$.

In other words, I have one more equation that number of variables, which is equal to the degree of the equation too.

Well, if $n = 1$ i.e. if the equations were all linear, basic linear algebra that I learned in undergraduate will help me. I can try to see if one of the equation comes as a linear combination of other equations.

However, when $n \geq 2$, I do not believe learning any similar theory.

Is there any hope of finding any sufficient conditions of $f_{1}, \ldots, f_{n}$ such that the above system will have a solution? Somehow, the situation seems more complicated when $n \geq 2$ to my naive brain.

Comment: Study Gröbner basis.

Comment: You can eliminate variables between polynomial equations of arbitrary degrees using [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), though the calculations are massive and better left to computers. In the end, you would obtain an equation in $k_j$ as the condition for the system to have a solution, then you would have to add the restriction to integers on top of that somehow.